# Interrupted Exception is not called when class is stopped

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupted-exception

There is a worker class which is executing the task. The code snippet is as follows:

```
public class Worker{
 executor.execute( new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         LOG.info("Task starting to execute");
         try {
             Thread.sleep(7000)`
         }catch (InterruptedException)
             LOG.info("Thread Interrupted");
         }
         LOG.info("Task Executed");
     }    

 }
```

}

Here when i stop worker class when it is in sleep mode, as per my knowledge Interrupted Exception should be thrown. But in reality, it's not. Instead it just stops. Can someone please clarify my misconception. I have seen lots of threads related to this question, still my doubt is not clear

Comment: And how do you "stop" your thread?

Comment: By clicking on stop button in the IDE

Comment: And how should a stopped/terminated JVM catch and log something?

Comment: Try to edit your question to include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @user3162418 The stop button in the IDE stops the entire Java Virtual Machine. Your code abruptly stops, and nothing else runs after clicking it.

Comment: Read something about the method `notify`. This will interrupt a thread and causes "him" to throw an `InterruptedException`.

Comment: @Tom, o.notify() and t.interrupt() are two completely different things.  o.notify() will change the state of thread that is blocked in a call to o.wait(), but it will not interrupt the thread.  In particular, it will not change the state of a thread that is blocked for any other reason (e.g., in a sleep() call or waiting for I/O).